# Funcion me devuelve contenido no llamado

Tags: javascript, funcion, retorno

Tengo la siguiente funcion

```js
const prueba= () =>{

  let equis = console.log("Hola")

}

console.log(prueba());
```

La funcion me devuelve "Hola undefined"
Entiendo que el undefined es porque estoy llamando a la funcion `prueba` y no retornar nada explicito, pero el ¿`Hola`? No entiendo porque me retornar algo de una variable que nisiquiera estoy llamando ni usando.

Comment: El undefined efectivamente es por la función, por otro lado cuando declaras una variable estás seteando un valor, eso se está procesando, si en lugar del valor pones una función como lo es un console.log("xxxx"), eso se ejecuta, puedes probar en una consola de  chrome, poner let prueba = console.log("Algo") y verás que devuelve Algo también.. Entonces estás entrando a la función, declarando el console.log que automáticamente se ejecuta y luego viene el undefined. Podrías setear una funcion X con un console.log solo adentro, y luego afuera hacer un let Y = X(), esto llamaría a la función.

Comment: El undefined se produce solo al ejecutarlo en la consola, y es porque el console.log que es una función, no retorna nada, por eso devuelve undefined, si haces una funcion X, le pones una variable ej: let texto = "hola" y luego haces un return de texto, al llamar a la función ya no habrá undefined, saldrá solo texto.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Te sale undefined porque no estás retornando ningún valor desde la función y estás imprimiendo el resultado.

Tienes 2 opciones.

- No imprimir el valor de retorno:

```js
const ejemplo = () => {
  console.log("Hola");
}

ejemplo(); // muestra solo Hola, sin el undefined
```

- Retornar el texto e imprimirlo:

```js
const ejemplo = () => {
  return "Hola";
}

console.log(ejemplo());
```

Esto sucede porque al no retornar un valor desde una función, javascript retorna undefined por defecto, es decir, tu función es lo mismo que poner:

```js
const ejemplo = () => {
  console.log("Hola");
  return undefined;
}
```

Recuerda que en las funciones flecha si el cuerpo de la función es solo una expresión, puedes omitir los corchetes y el return:

```js
const ejemplo = () => "Hola";

console.log(ejemplo());
```

Respondiendo a tu pregunta, imprime Hola porque lo tienes dentro de un console.log(), e imprime undefined porque tienes la llamada a la función dentro de otro console.log();

Answer (score 2):

Primero, la función no devuelve nada (undefined) porque no hay ningún `return`.
Segundo, el `console.log` escribe algo en la consola, no devuelve nada, así que el `let equis = console.log("Hola")` no tiene ningún sentido (`equis` valdrà tambien `undefined`).
Para terminar, la línea `console.log(prueba());` primero ejecutará la función, por eso primero muestra "`hola`" en consola, y luego mostrará lo que retorne la función, que es nada, o sea, el "`undefined`", por eso la saluda a consola será "`hola undefined`", pero no devuelve nada.
Quizas lo que pretendías se parece a esto:

```js
const prueba= () =>{
  let equis = "Hola";
  return equis; // Devuelve el valor de equis.
}
console.log(prueba()); // Muestra en consola lo que devuelve la función.
```

Comment: no es lo que el consulta el  dice ...Entiendo que el undefined es porque estoy llamando a la función prueba y no retornar nada explicito.... si consulta porque imprime Hola

Comment: Sí, es lo que he escrito en la respuesta.

Comment: Es que para mi es claro que no pretende retornar nada Por eso esta de mas según mi punto de vista decir quizás lo que pretendías hacer es esto?Es que en realidad de acuerdo al perfil de quien consulta no entiendo porque tiene dudas de que si ejecuta dentro de la función a console.log('hola')  siempre se ejecutara al llamar a la función.No pretendo hacer una critica hacia vos quiero enfocar hacia lo que el que consulta que dice no comprender saludos

Comment: Tiene ud. razón, el problema es que el código tiene tantos problemas que no queda claro del todo sus intenciones. Yo me he limitado a poner un ejemplo.

Answer (score 0):

> Como bien decís no definís ningún valor de retorno explicito de la arrow luego
> console.log(funcion())  ejecuta a la funcion y tambien imprime undefined
> la funcion imprime hola y eso es lo que hace ademas de definir a
> un valor undefined y no retornar nada
> El codigo de la arrow ejecuta la funcion console.log('hola') y luego asigna un
> valor undefined a una variable

```js
// console.log() si no retorna explicitamente algo 
//retorna undefined
const prueba= () =>{
// le estas pidiendo que imprima hola

  let equis = console.log("Hola")
 // y luego
  console.log(typeof(equis))// undefined

}

console.log(prueba());// hola ,undefined,undefined
```